# jQuery UI drag - position top and left px value is float - how to override?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm building a simple drag and drop application. However, when I drop the element on a droppable it adjusts itself by a pixel either top, left or sometimes both.

Looking at the console. when I drag the element its top, left position shows as (if I drag to top left of droppable): `top:0.5px; left:0.71875px`

So I get that the slight adjustment as I drop is the browser rounding these coordinates to the nearest int. But surely these values shouldn't be floats to begin with?

Comment: Please post a complete code example in your question.

Comment: This is part of a much larger project. There's not much I can post that would be of any use to anyone.

Comment: The question is unclear, please expand and provide a simplified version of your code, or maybe a fiddle to see the problem.